# Python function parameter inserted via command line

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to give input/argument for a python function from the command line (by creating batch file)?

For example: I have a python file example.py:

```
import sys

date = sys.argv

print('The date is: ',date)
```

I want to run this code without opening the python script itself but by running bat file. However I want to be flexible on the function argument such as I can change the date. So when I run the bat file, I want the command prompt to ask me:

```
Please insert date:
```

And when I put the date (for example 01-01-2020), then the python script will run and print: The date is 01-01-2020.

I tried using the batch file as follow:

```
@echo off
set /p date="Please insert date: "
```

But of course this will not be linked to python when I run the batch file and insert the date in command line. I am missing the way of connecting batch file - cmd input  - python function. Thanks

Comment: `date = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: as a side note, `set /p date=` is not a good idea, `%date%` exists as a predefined environment variable.

Comment: thanks Gerhard, you are correct. Lets make it as date_ instead of date.

Comment: One of the roles of a python script is to replace batch files. You could just have python do the prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that easily with variables in batch.

```
import sys

date = sys.argv[1]

print('The date is: ' + date)
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off
set /p "date_=Please insert date: "
python example.py %date_%
```

Comment: I know it, but teheh May asked for the variable ``%date%``

Comment: thanks, i change the python code from date_ in python script as well. But I still have an error when I ran the bat file: IndexError: list index out of range. My batch code:
c:
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
@echo off
set /p "date_ = Please insert date: "
python G:\My_File\example.py %date_%
pause
conda deactivate

Comment: yes I tried 01-01-2020 and '01-01-2020'. And I also tried to change python script as date_ = str(sys.argv[1]) and in cmd input '01-01-2020'